# How to achieve this organza-like rubbery cloth? (like @catelloo)

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials

[image: catelloodrop]

This is 'drop.png' by @catelloo on Instagram. I think they made it using C4D but I wonder if the same effect can be achieved using Blender. I'm a total newbie. Thanks :)